# Target of URI doesn't exist:package:gradient_input_border/gradient_input_border.dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am new to flutter from android background,
I have imported a futter project both in VS and Android studio but I am getting Target URI dosen't expsist on these import statement.

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:gradient_input_border/gradient_input_border.dart';
```

My pubsec.yaml file is below here.

```
name: Emall
description: Ecommerce website

environment:
 sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
 scoped_model: ^1.0.1
 rxdart: ^0.24.0
 http: ^0.12.0+2
 json_annotation: ^2.0.0
 flutter_html: ^1.0.2
 flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
 cached_network_image: ^2.3.3
 shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
 country_code_picker: ^1.1.7
 url_launcher: ^5.4.11
 timeago: ^2.0.26
 flutter_rating_bar: ^3.0.1+1
 webview_flutter: ^0.3.18+1
 font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
 share: ^0.6.3+3
 place_picker: 0.9.16
 location: 2.3.5
 fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
 flutter_paystack: 1.0.2+1
 sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.2
 image_picker: ^0.6.6+4
 flutter_webview_plugin: 0.3.10+1
 smooth_star_rating: ^1.1.1
 flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
 firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
 google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
 flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
 fab_circular_menu: ^0.1.4
 google_fonts: ^0.3.5
 stripe_payment: ^1.0.7
 network_to_file_image: ^2.3.1
 barcode_scan: ^3.0.1
 geocoder: ^0.2.1
 firebase_core: 0.5.0
 firebase_analytics: 6.0.0
 firebase_storage: 4.0.0
 cloud_firestore: 0.14.0+2
 photo_view: ^0.10.2
 intro_slider: ^2.3.1
 firebase_messaging: 7.0.0
 rounded_loading_button: ^1.0.14
 pin_code_fields: ^5.2.0
 lottie: ^0.7.0+1
 webview_cookie_manager: ^1.0.4
 flutter_native_splash: ^0.1.9
 change_app_package_name: ^0.1.2
 flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
   - lib/assets/images/
   - lib/assets/images/intro/

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter

flutter_localizations:
  sdk: flutter

flutter_native_splash:
  image: lib/assets/images/splash.png
  color: "ffffff"

fonts:
  - family: MStoreIcons
  - fonts:
  - asset: lib/assets/fonts/Icons/MStoreIcons.ttf

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "lib/assets/images/icon.png"
```

Things I have already tried

- Commands

  ```
  flutter clean 
  flutter pub get
  flutter packages upgrade
  ```
- Invalidate Cache / Restart on Android Studio
- Restarted Visual studio.

Comment: Where `gradient_input_border.dart` is imported from ?

Comment: doesn't it comes within material design ?

Comment: No you must use it in your `pubspec.yaml` file. The package can be found here https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_input_border/install

Comment: got it bro.. and for localization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [gradient_input_package](https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_input_border/install).

```
dependencies:

   // Add this dependency under dependecies as shown.
   gradient_input_border: ^1.0.0
```

Then run `flutter pub get`.

Edit 1:
Try this for flutter_localizations,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: it worked and for localization which dependency should i add?

Comment: @ManzoorAhmad i have edited ans for flutter_localizations.